# Assign a div name to a variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know why `$bz_div.length < 1` or `$bz_div.remove()` don't work while `$('#bz-ph').length < 1` or `$('#bz-ph').remove()` do?

Can't I assign a div name like `$('#bz-ph')` to a variable?

```
var show = function (options) {
    var $gallery    = $('#gallery');
    var $img        = $('.bz-img');
    var $bz_div     = $('#bz-ph');

    $img.click(function () {
        var $img_path   = $(this).data('image');
        print($bz_div.length);
        /* Prevents: double click = double gallery layer */
        if ($bz_div.length < 1) {
            $gallery.append(output(options, $img_path));
        } else {
            $bz_div.remove();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Do you have some code elsewhere which affects the value of `$bz_div`?

Comment: Should be fine assigning variables like that. Try `console.log($bz_div);` to see the value it holds

Comment: Maybe the div does not exist yet while you are assigning it to the variable?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Totally right Sebastian! I have to create the div then hide it (I deleted my previous comment 'cause the solution there was a completely mistake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this $('#bz-ph'), you're getting the object in dom by jquery. It's a shortcut to document.getElementById("bz-ph").

To assign a div to a variable, you can do something like this.

```
var obj = $('#bz-ph');
$(obj).fadeOut();
```

Comment: Exactly, as Sebastian pointed out that's the problem. As you suggested, I should create the div then hide it (I deleted my previous comment 'cause the solution there was a completely mistake)